# Installing gstreamer error

Tags: debian, installation, gstreamer

I have a problem at installing gstreamer on Debian.

```
# grep . /etc/*-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux stretch/sid"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

I follow here
http://www.pixhawk.org/peripherals/onboard_computers/video_streaming
And this is what I get.

```
# sudo apt-get install "^gstreamer1.0*"
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-videosink' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-alsa' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-dbg' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-mpeg2enc' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-doc' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-rtsp-dbg' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'libgstreamer1.0-dev' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-faac' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-tools' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-good' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-qapt' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'libgstreamer1.0-0-dbg' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-espeak' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-nice' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-videosource' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-crystalhd' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-rtsp' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-base' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-audiosource' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-really-bad' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-clutter' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-pocketsphinx' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-dbg' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-doc' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-visualization' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-lame' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-x' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-vaapi-doc' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-libav' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-dbg' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-dbg' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-doc' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-doc' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-dvswitch' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-vaapi' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-libav-dbg' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-packagekit' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'libgstreamer1.0-0' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-doc' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-audiosink' for regex 'gstreamer1.0'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gstreamer1.0-libav-dbg : Depends: gstreamer1.0-libav (= 1:1.6.2-dmo1) but 1:1.8.1-dmo1 is to be installed
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-dbg : Depends: gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad (= 1.8.1-2) but 1:1.8.1-dmo1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Dose anyone know what is that mean, and how to solve it??

Answer (score 0):

why on earth are you installing all gstreamer packages - including dbg versions etc? .. well maybe it should work - it sounds crazy.. anyway, what happens when you just try to install the gstreamer1.0-libav? same error? in that case check [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170808/install-gstreamer1-0-libav-mainly-libavcodec54-on-debian-wheezy) - I hade the same problem..

You will have to use [this](http://www.deb-multimedia.org/) repo..

Well you are using sid so use these:

```
deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org sid main non-free
```

or

```
deb ftp://ftp.deb-multimedia.org sid main non-free
```

I hope you know [how to add](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList) another source to debian..

Then just `apt-get update` and try again to install it

Comment: Thank you for answering always. That is already in there, and actually my friend solved it and I don't heard how he did yet.

Comment: @Potato ok, you may post another answer when you find out how he did that :)